# Зачем нужен draw9patch?

Tags: android

Зачем нужен draw9patch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классический пример - нужно сделать кнопку с красивыми краями. Дизайнеру нарисовать не проблема, проблема начинается тогда, когда приходит осознание того, что кнопки бывают разного размера. Просто растянуть не получиться - изображение будет искажено. Не рисовать же тысячи кнопок? Но выход есть. Представьте себе, что кнопку поделили на 9 прямоугольников, 3х3. Теперь процесс растягивания стает значительно проще. Центральная часть растягивается во все стороны, угловые не трогаются, а боковые растягиваются только в одном направлении.

Системе найти эти края для разделения очень просто - по сторонам изображения есть небольшие  черные квадраты.

Вот любители даже сделали [сайт](http://draw9patch.com), где можно подгрузить свою картинку и покрутить размеры, увидеть, как оно изменяется.